# R twitteR oAuth: unable to complete authentification

Tags: r, twitter-oauth

I am unable to  complete twitter access using R....I am using R studio.... My code is as follows....

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
library(httr)
library(base64enc)
#library(ROAuth)
library(twitteR)
#set_config(use_proxy(url='10.32.192.30',8080))
#download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",destfile="cacert.pem")
api_key<-"aveDy5RnM*****LmmgJ08TmsJ"
api_secret<-"BmbnOO06LKS********UDaoohYGgv4L1kp5RguYKERA3K7UDAR"
access_token<-"43281661-FcRyQOJo*********GZLl8TD732yTtsRSqddISm25"
access_token_secret<-"BNV7gIsLYA0********j5epXDXRI8IYgAANWw4N1JT7Ug"
x<-setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
```

i get error
    `Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
    This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'`

Comment: Are you getting any error output?  Are you certain that your OAuth credentials be correct?

Comment: I have chaged the code and added the error which i am getting. Also I am working behind a proxy ....so Is that the reason? I tried to get around that  by use_proxy but still same error.

Comment: The proxy might be a problem because OAuth needs to redirect back to your machine, and the presence of a proxy could interfere with that.  Try connecting directly from your machine if possible.

Comment: I also  think the proxy is a problem.....and I cant find a way  around it.... I cant change internet setting s of this PC....its an office PC.... anyways...I will try on another laptop and try with an open internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(twitteR)
consumer_key = "your consumer_key"
consumer_secret = "your consumer_secret"
access_token = "your access_token"
access_secret = "your access_secret"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_secret)

#[1] "Using direct authentication"
#Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
#1: Yes
#2: No

#Selection: 1
```

Try this code, it should work.

Comment: I tried..... I have updated the code in the question....still   same error (also added)

Comment: I am working with the same code what I have posted. It is working fine for me. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was my pc ....I didnt have admin privileges....!! putting  it into   a pc with admin privileges solved the issue